# Facet adding itself to search parameters in pager when not selected

Tags: 7, views, search

I have a number of search pages that use views, each displays a large number of facets using Search & Facet APIs.

I've noticed recently that when I use the pager I get directed to a url with an extra parameter:

```
current pagination url - mysite.com?&&field_1=all&page=1
correct pagination url - mysite.com?&page=1
```

It's only caused by a single taxonomy facet, if I turn that facet off it disappears. However I have other taxonomy facets, which are aside from vocabulary, identical and they don't cause the problem. Has anyone come across this before or have any ideas where it might come from?

Comment: There is a radio button on taxonomy facets called "Add facet for missing values". Is that doing it? 

Or is it actually coming from Views with a contextual filter on that particular taxonomy?